# How to get right line number when Carp::croaked?

Tags: perl, exception

Is there a proper way to get a line number where`croak` was called?

In the following example I get into `$stack` :

- line 22, where last subroutine  (`l`) was called
- line 44, where `try`-block is terminated
- all the other calls in the stack

but I'd like to know the line 28, where I call the `croak` (or `confess`);

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

{
  package Module;
  use strict; use warnings;
  use Carp qw(croak confess longmess);
  our @CARP_NOT = qw(Try::Tiny);
  use Try::Tiny;

  sub i {
    my ($x) = @_;
    j($x);
  }

  sub j {
    my ($x) = @_;
    k($x);
  }

  sub k {
    my ($x) = @_;
    l($x);
  }

  sub l {
    my ($x) = @_;
    my $stack = longmess();
    croak( { data => 1, stack => $stack } ) if $x =~ /\D/; # or confess
    return $x;
  }
  1;
}

use strict; use warnings; use 5.014;

import Module;
use Try::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;

try {
  Module::i("x");
} catch {
  say Dumper $_;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
sub _lm { longmess() }

sub l {
  my ($x) = @_;
  die( { data => 1, stack => _lm() } ) if $x =~ /\D/;
  return $x;
}
```

or

```perl
sub l {
  my ($x) = @_;
  local $Carp::CarpLevel = $Carp::CarpLevel - 1;
  die( { data => 1, stack => longmess() } ) if $x =~ /\D/;
  return $x;
}
```

or

```perl
sub mycroak { die( { @_, stack => longmess() } ); }

sub l {
  my ($x) = @_;
  mycroak( data => 1 ) if $x =~ /\D/;
  return $x;
}
```

(Replaced `croak` with `die` because you didn't take advantage of any of `croak`'s functionality.)

Comment: You nailed it: it is my first try to use Carp-family and I need just `longmess`'s functionality. The first one is so simple and elegant workaround. How I did not think on that? Thank you!

Comment: I personally prefer the last one. Don't have to use `stack => _lm()` all over the place. Also avoids the extra `{ }`

Answer (score 2):

From the BUGS section of [Carp documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp#BUGS):

*The Carp routines don't handle exception objects currently. If called with a first argument that is a reference, they simply call die() or warn(), as appropriate.*

If you simply call `confess()` without an arg, the line number will be reported.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the string created by `longmess`. After all, they don't even try to print the exception itself (a hash ref).